# Как удалить всю строчку вместе с индексом в pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, фильтры

Всем привет, мне нужно полностью удалить строку 888 у объекта DataFrame.
Как это сделать?
Буду очень признателен.

```
0         3   7.2500  22.0    male
1         1  71.2833  38.0  female
2         3   7.9250  26.0  female
3         1  53.1000  35.0  female
4         3   8.0500  35.0    male
..      ...      ...   ...     ...
886       2  13.0000  27.0    male
887       1  30.0000  19.0  female
888       3  23.4500   NaN  female
889       1  30.0000  26.0    male
890       3   7.7500  32.0    male
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исходный DF:

```
In [79]: df
Out[79]:
     1        2     3       4
0
0    3   7.2500  22.0    male
1    1  71.2833  38.0  female
2    3   7.9250  26.0  female
3    1  53.1000  35.0  female
4    3   8.0500  35.0    male
886  2  13.0000  27.0    male
887  1  30.0000  19.0  female
888  3  23.4500   NaN  female
889  1  30.0000  26.0    male
890  3   7.7500  32.0    male
```

удаляем строку/строки по значениям индекса:

*способ 1*:

```
df = df.drop(index=[888])
```

*способ 2*:

```
df = df.query("index not in [888]")
```

или:

```
df = df.query("index != 888")
```

результат:

```
In [81]: df
Out[81]:
     1        2     3       4
0
0    3   7.2500  22.0    male
1    1  71.2833  38.0  female
2    3   7.9250  26.0  female
3    1  53.1000  35.0  female
4    3   8.0500  35.0    male
886  2  13.0000  27.0    male
887  1  30.0000  19.0  female
889  1  30.0000  26.0    male
890  3   7.7500  32.0    male
```

---

**ответ-бонус:**

> можно как-то сделать индексирование по порядку?

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

результат:

```
In [94]: df
Out[94]:
   1        2     3       4
0  3   7.2500  22.0    male
1  1  71.2833  38.0  female
2  3   7.9250  26.0  female
3  1  53.1000  35.0  female
4  3   8.0500  35.0    male
5  2  13.0000  27.0    male
6  1  30.0000  19.0  female
7  1  30.0000  26.0    male
8  3   7.7500  32.0    male
```

Comment: Это решает мою проблему, но можно как-то сделать индексирование по порядку и при этом всё также удалить строчку? А то у вас идёт 887, 889.

Comment: @kali_xyyali, можно - дополнил ответ)

Comment: Спасибо, вы очень мне помогли